# Can not compile aplication.scss rails can't find bootstrap-sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm trying to use **sass** and **sublime text** for my Rails project, but when I try to compile my **aplication.css.scss** file, sublime shows me this error:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
```

**Gemfile**

```
...
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
...
```

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "favourites.scss";
@import "custom.scss";
```

I use sublime Sass and BuildOnSave packages for compiling sass.

**My assets directory:**

```
/app
    /assets
        /stylesheets
            /bourbon
            application.css.scss
            custom.css
            custom.css.map
            custom.scss
            favourites.scss
```

Comment: What's with the ```bootstrap-sprockets``` ? It's not needed with Bootstrap. the `@import 'bootstraop'` should be enough to use Bootstrap SASS in your app.

Comment: According to bootstrap sass doc here I have to use it.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

This is because `bootstrap-sprockets` don't exist in your currect directory. SASS @import directive just import files who exists.

You can download that file again, directly, [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-sprockets.scss).